# create proper association in cakephp 3

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, model, cakephp-3.0

I want to create proper relation b/w two table. So that when I get data from `lease` table I will be able to get `price` table data too. Price table can have multiple id of `lease` table.

The structure of tables are

**Lease Table**

[image]

**Price Table**

[image]

Where `id` of `lease` table related to `lease_id` of price table.

I have tried with following code but not able to get data.

```
class LeasesTable extends Table {

    /**
     * Initialize method
     *
     * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
     * @return void
     */
    public function initialize(array $config) {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->table('leases');

        $this->primaryKey('id');

        $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

        $this->belongsTo('Offices', [
            'foreignKey' => 'office_type',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Countries', [
            'foreignKey' => 'country_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('Areas', [
            'foreignKey' => 'area_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER'
        ]);
        $this->belongsToMany('id', [
            'foreignKey' => 'lease_id',
            'joinType' => 'INNER',
            'joinTable' => 'Prices',
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Association you described is Lease **has many** Prices - so you should use following code in LeasesTable.php:

```
$this->hasMany("Prices", [
    "foreignKey" => "lease_id"
]);
```

More info: [HasMany Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#hasmany-associations)